# Как удалить конкретный объект(элемент) из массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, фильтрация

Как удалить из массива объекты, id которых > 40

```js
let arr = [
    {"id": 53, "name": "Dmitriy", "phone": "+380664786142", "age": "22"},
    {"id": 28, "name": "Andrew", "phone": "+380994533332", "age": "22"},
    {"id": 37, "name": "Vika", "phone": "+380664786140", "age": "25"}
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для фильтрации массива, лучше всего воспользоваться встроенным методом **.filter()**

> **filter()** возвращает новый массив. Принимает коллбэк функцию, в которую передается текущий итерируемый элемент массива. Если результат работы коллбэк функции вернет true, то текущий элемент будет добавлен в возвращаемый массив.

```js
let arr = [
    { id: 53, name: 'Dmitriy', phone: '+380664786142', age: '22' },
    { id: 28, name: 'Andrew', phone: '+380994533332', age: '22' },
    { id: 37, name: 'Vika', phone: '+380664786140', age: '25' },
];

const arrNew = arr.filter(el => el.id <= 40)

console.log(arrNew);
```

Comment: Я разобрался в своей ошибке, ещё раз спасибо! Можно ли избежать мутации без присваивания результата новой переменной?

Comment: @Elmir Тут либо мутация(изменение текущего массива), либо новый массив. Еще можно написать функцию, которая будет менять текущий массив по заданным условиям, однако это та же мутация(изменение), но уже "осознанная". Создайте вопрос с интересующими вас деталями, и, скорее всего, найдется решение )